# Prism / Resolution of Names / Clarification from Documentation

Tags: prism

I'm looking to share an EF Context between "data manager" objects to ensure change tracking occurs under one context as opposed to handling multiple contexts...so I'm looking into named context... but in review of this documentation, I felt it wasn't clear, and I want to ensure my assumption is correct, and if so, update the documentation:  [here](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/xamarin-forms/dependency-injection/registering-types.html) PRISM documents the resolution of named instances via a constructor:

My assumption is that the named typed "carservice" is matched to the named parameter in the constructor to select which concrete class should be reference to that parameter based on the IVehicleService.

[image]

Is my assumption correct - either way I'll create a pull request to clarify the documentation..Either way, answering the question here will add reference to clarification/handling of named instances in PRISM.

Comment: Which container are you using? With Unity, the red arrows do not happen automatically, you have to specify that during registration (clumsy and fragile).

Comment: We are using Unity at the moment... suggestions for an IOC that can handle the scoping of an object to inject?

Comment: You can have a look into ninject, I remember that doing things like this, but I'd try to avoid it in the first place (putting semantics into parameter names). Try to find the bug introduced by some refactoring that changes a few of those names or the ordering of the parameters...

Comment: I actually think that the answer... I need to refactor.  IOC is to manage lifetime/scope of object... this problem derives from an EF Context that I'm trying to inject into multiple other objects and maintain scope of the EF Context across those other objects... using a constructor and the IOC is likely not a great solution... I think I need to refactor.. but I'm not quite there yet... thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is NOT correct assumption, and it's not possible in Unity - I refactored to avoid.

One solution that I didn't try was to simply another interface (came to mind much later), was  inheriting from an existing interface, and registers the "new" interface to use a specific constructor.  As I'm new to Unity, I thought I would mention. I'm answering my own question, as I can't don't think I can give credit to a comment, and I HATE leaving questions unanswered on this site!